# Copy a data frame in a function

Tags: r

I want to copy data frame `a` to a new data frame `b` inside a function.

```
a <- mtcars

saveData <- function(x, y){
    y <- x
    return(y)
}

saveData(a, b)
```

In this example, the function should create the object/data frame `b`. `b` should be a copy of `a` (i.e., `mtcars`)

The crux is to flexibly "name" objects.

I excessively played around with `assign()`, `deparse()`, and `substitute()`, but I could not make it work.

Comment: You are not returning anything in your function. You need to add `return(y)`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I adjusted the example. However, `b` is not created.

Comment: Shouldn't the last object in the function be returned automatically? Using `return(y)` would be cleaner code but it wouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good pracrtice to save the data in global environment from a function. However if you want to do it here is a way :

```
saveData <- function(x, y){
   assign(deparse(substitute(y)), x, envir = parent.frame())
}

a <- mtcars
b
```

> Error: object 'b' not found

```
saveData(a, b)
b
#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. In my ealier attempts, I was unaware of `envir = ...`.  As a side note: instead of `parent.frame()`, I used `.GlobalEnv` as provided by Sotos' answer.

Comment: Why are you showing how to follow bad practice? You can safely assume that people just ignore the first sentence of you answer, in particular if you don't show good practice.

Comment: I use this function for development/debugging purposes and do not plan to use the function once development is done. But why is it bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to use `list2env`, but you have to convert to a named list, so your second argument will need to be a character, i.e.

```
saveData <- function(x, y) {
     v1 <- setNames(list(x), y)
     list2env(v1, envir = .GlobalEnv)
 }

saveData(a, 'b')

b
#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#.....
```

**NOTE:** I wouldn't recommend adding staff to your global environment. It is better to keep them in lists

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I marked Ronak's answer as correct, because in my setting, it is more convenient to not pass character arguments. As a side note: I use this function for development/debugging purposes and do not plan to use the function once development is done. But why is it bad practice?